# How can I parsing Firebase JSON output

Tags: android, arrays, json, retrofit, jsonparser

```
   {
    "-KrwJP0nYf1IUqY-YdXo": {
        "desc": "pdf desc 4",
        "downloadUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fireapp-a889c.appspot.com/o/PdfFile%2F1503177372?alt=media&token=36436f90-8a90-42f2-bf9d-35ac121b9ca7",
        "title": "pdf 4",
        "uid": "0HEj0gbzmcgqNc9nSXAIHqjo15p1",
        "username": "userq"
    },
    "-KrwK2DSmF7UA-SD-VOM": {
        "desc": "asdadadad",
        "downloadUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fireapp-a889c.appspot.com/o/PdfFile%2F37?alt=media&token=701d3aca-8e9e-48c8-ae45-5aab4b4c37ad",
        "title": "adsasdadad",
        "uid": "0HEj0gbzmcgqNc9nSXAIHqjo15p1",
        "username": "userq"
    },
    "-KrwL69kWDatEftRf3C0": {
        "desc": "sdfsfd",
        "downloadUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fireapp-a889c.appspot.com/o/PdfFile%2F1503177856?alt=media&token=e0dea2ff-8311-4c00-9c1b-6402cb69e929",
        "title": "sdf",
        "uid": "0HEj0gbzmcgqNc9nSXAIHqjo15p1",
        "username": "userq"
    },
    "-KrwLdA21nomZUToFOjh": {
        "desc": "gdfgdfgdfgdfg",
        "downloadUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fireapp-a889c.appspot.com/o/PdfFile%2F1503177996?alt=media&token=7d15cb11-f7c0-4086-aefe-5c39964ab83f",
        "title": "dfgdfgdfghdf",
        "uid": "0HEj0gbzmcgqNc9nSXAIHqjo15p1",
        "username": "userq"
    }
}
```

Its my json text. How can i parsing with retrofit in android. It has unique object name.

My json adress : https://fireapp-a889c.firebaseio.com/PdfContent.json

Comment: Try this website : http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: I know pojo,but pojo create how many are there unique object name.

Comment: after you parse you can change the fields names just leave the SerializedName Annoation.

Comment: @spoiler have you checked my answer?

Comment: @volodymyr-khodonovych doesn't work

Comment: What is the issue? I've tried by my self and it returns the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String jsonData = "{\n" +
            "    \"-KrwJP0nYf1IUqY-YdXo\": {\n" +
            "        \"desc\": \"pdf desc 4\",\n" +
            "        \"downloadUrl\": \"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fireapp-a889c.appspot.com/o/PdfFile%2F1503177372?alt=media&token=36436f90-8a90-42f2-bf9d-35ac121b9ca7\",\n" +
            "        \"title\": \"pdf 4\",\n" +
            "        \"uid\": \"0HEj0gbzmcgqNc9nSXAIHqjo15p1\",\n" +
            "        \"username\": \"userq\"\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    \"-KrwK2DSmF7UA-SD-VOM\": {\n" +
            "        \"desc\": \"asdadadad\",\n" +
            "        \"downloadUrl\": \"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fireapp-a889c.appspot.com/o/PdfFile%2F37?alt=media&token=701d3aca-8e9e-48c8-ae45-5aab4b4c37ad\",\n" +
            "        \"title\": \"adsasdadad\",\n" +
            "        \"uid\": \"0HEj0gbzmcgqNc9nSXAIHqjo15p1\",\n" +
            "        \"username\": \"userq\"\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    \"-KrwL69kWDatEftRf3C0\": {\n" +
            "        \"desc\": \"sdfsfd\",\n" +
            "        \"downloadUrl\": \"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fireapp-a889c.appspot.com/o/PdfFile%2F1503177856?alt=media&token=e0dea2ff-8311-4c00-9c1b-6402cb69e929\",\n" +
            "        \"title\": \"sdf\",\n" +
            "        \"uid\": \"0HEj0gbzmcgqNc9nSXAIHqjo15p1\",\n" +
            "        \"username\": \"userq\"\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    \"-KrwLdA21nomZUToFOjh\": {\n" +
            "        \"desc\": \"gdfgdfgdfgdfg\",\n" +
            "        \"downloadUrl\": \"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fireapp-a889c.appspot.com/o/PdfFile%2F1503177996?alt=media&token=7d15cb11-f7c0-4086-aefe-5c39964ab83f\",\n" +
            "        \"title\": \"dfgdfgdfghdf\",\n" +
            "        \"uid\": \"0HEj0gbzmcgqNc9nSXAIHqjo15p1\",\n" +
            "        \"username\": \"userq\"\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}";
    try {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        Iterator<String> iterator = object.keys();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            JSONObject obj = object.getJSONObject(iterator.next());
            Log.d("TAG", obj.toString());
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

here you just need to pass the Your JSON string into `jsonData`
so, you get output like,

**Output:**

```
{"desc":"pdf desc 4","downloadUrl":"https:\/\/firebasestorage.googleapis.com\/v0\/b\/fireapp-a889c.appspot.com\/o\/PdfFile%2F1503177372?alt=media&token=36436f90-8a90-42f2-bf9d-35ac121b9ca7","title":"pdf 4","uid":"0HEj0gbzmcgqNc9nSXAIHqjo15p1","username":"userq"}
{"desc":"asdadadad","downloadUrl":"https:\/\/firebasestorage.googleapis.com\/v0\/b\/fireapp-a889c.appspot.com\/o\/PdfFile%2F37?alt=media&token=701d3aca-8e9e-48c8-ae45-5aab4b4c37ad","title":"adsasdadad","uid":"0HEj0gbzmcgqNc9nSXAIHqjo15p1","username":"userq"}
{"desc":"sdfsfd","downloadUrl":"https:\/\/firebasestorage.googleapis.com\/v0\/b\/fireapp-a889c.appspot.com\/o\/PdfFile%2F1503177856?alt=media&token=e0dea2ff-8311-4c00-9c1b-6402cb69e929","title":"sdf","uid":"0HEj0gbzmcgqNc9nSXAIHqjo15p1","username":"userq"}
{"desc":"gdfgdfgdfgdfg","downloadUrl":"https:\/\/firebasestorage.googleapis.com\/v0\/b\/fireapp-a889c.appspot.com\/o\/PdfFile%2F1503177996?alt=media&token=7d15cb11-f7c0-4086-aefe-5c39964ab83f","title":"dfgdfgdfghdf","uid":"0HEj0gbzmcgqNc9nSXAIHqjo15p1","username":"userq"}
```

Comment: Thanks,How can I retrofit this? Model class and callback API?

Comment: but I think this one easy way because if you use retrofit then ultimately return the JSONObject

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message  

Doesn't work, error null exception

Comment: can you please try above one may test two-time in an android studio it will give me perfect output which one may show you in above answer

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Add dependency in your build.gradle file

```
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.4'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
```

As firebase JSON is a map `Map<String,Object>` you can retrieve data in following way

```
public final class ApiService {
private  static Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://fireapp-a889c.firebaseio.com/")
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
        .build();

public static Retrofit getRetrofit() {
    return retrofit;
}
}
```

Request interface:

```
public interface FirebaseApi {
    @GET("PdfContent.json")
    Observable<Map<String, Object>> getFirebaseResponse();
}
```

And then call it where you need:

```
 ApiService.getRetrofit().create(FirebaseApi.class)
            .getFirebaseResponse()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<Map<String, Object>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Map<String, Object> response) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "onNext: " + response);
                }
            });
```

It returns exactly what you need. After that, you can you use iterator to convert output date into the list of items with appropriate ids.

Comment: Can not resolve Schedulers,AndroidSchedulers and getRetrofit method

Comment: You have to use additional dependencies, I've posted in updated answer

Comment: Sorry, there was one more missing dependencies in gradle file 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0' . Changed already

Comment: probably you've made some mistake, try to check if you everything is correct or look through similar examples in the Internet

Comment: Sorry I could not do it. It's a bit of a complex solution